# scala String to scala.xml.Elem

Tags: xml, string, scala, scala-xml

I have to convert a string into XML

```
scala> val string="<play><scala></scala></play>"
string: String = <play><scala></scala></play>

scala> val xml=(<play><scala></scala></play>)
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <play><scala></scala></play>
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
scala> scala.xml.XML.loadString(string)
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <play><scala/></play>
```