# how I extract field from xml string in java / scala

Tags: java, xml, scala

I have following as a string and I want to get values from it like response code and response message how I can get that

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="https://exa.org/UpdateOrder/">
<soapenv:Body>
<tns:UpdateResponse xmlns="https://exa.org/UpdateOrder/">
<tns:responseCode>0</tns:responseCode>
<tns:responseMessage/>
</tns:UpdateResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Use the DOM parser that's built into the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard scala xml library could make short work of it: [The standard Scala XML library](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml)

Check out [scala String to scala.xml.Elem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152738/scala-string-to-scala-xml-elem) to convert the string to an scala xml element.
Then you can navigate and parse the xml tree using xpath like sequences in the scala xml library.  Something like this:

```
val xmlNode = scala.xml.XML.loadString(string)
val responseCode = (xmlNode \ "Body" \ "UpdateResponse" \ "responseCode").text
```

Comment: I edited my answer.  There was a typo with capitalization on "ResponseCode".